# Trigger cursor positioning and selection on going to Normal mode or ESC map

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

Anyone knows how can I trigger cursor positioning and selection from python when going to Normal?

This is [the script](https://github.com/oblitum/YouCompleteMe/blob/clang_complete-params/python/ycm/param_completion/clang_complete.py) and I had to comment out the <kbd>ESC</kbd> mapping [in this commit](https://github.com/oblitum/YouCompleteMe/commit/941450a).

Relevant plugin source code is bellow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import vim

#How can we fetch the first param on going to normal Mode without problems?!
vim.command( "inoremap <silent> <buffer> <esc> <c-\><c-n>:py clang_complete.firstParam()<cr>" )

r = re.compile( "@[^@]+\$" )

def firstParam():
  line = vim.current.line
  row, col = vim.current.window.cursor

  result = r.search(line)
  if result is None:
    vim.command('call feedkeys("\<esc>", "n")')
    return

  selectParams( *result.span() )

def selectParams( start, end  ):
  row, _ = vim.current.window.cursor
  vim.current.window.cursor = row, start
  isInclusive = vim.options["selection"] == "inclusive"
  vim.command( 'call feedkeys("\<c-\>\<c-n>v%dl\<c-g>", "n")' %
               ( end - start - isInclusive ) )
```

An <kbd>ESC</kbd> mapping gives issues with arrows keys in terminal on insert mode, and providing a [simple InsertLeave](https://github.com/oblitum/YouCompleteMe/commit/7aa20e9c0004eb99299ee0f0a18d5415ac5dfda5) auto command didn't work well, it was operating much slower than the mapping and it wasn't correctly setting cursor positioning to make the selection, so the selection was over the wrong place.

I also consider an alternative approach for doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I don't see how `InsertLeave` can be slower. Are you sure you don't have any `:imap` starting with `<Esc>` or bad `'timeoutlen'` that adds a delay to exiting insert mode?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat I have [a bunch of vim plugins](https://gist.github.com/oblitum/5565974) and `:au InsertLeave` gives this list `InsertLeave :let @/=''`,   `BufKill  InsertLeave * call UltiSnips#LeavingInsertMode()`,   `youcompleteme  InsertLeave * call s:OnInsertLeave()`

Comment: @IngoKarkat ah! `timeoutlen` is set to 1000! Now I have to figure out who sets this.

Comment: @IngoKarkat even then, I'm not sure fixing this will fix the positioning issue.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I'm just learning about `timeoutlen` and 1000 seems the default anyway.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Hi, I'd just like to inform you that a simple `au InsertLeave * echom "hello"` has no delay to show the message on InsertLeave when I have **no `.vimrc`** file, if I create an **empty** one, the message shows up with a delay.

Comment: It would help if you copied relevant parts of the script instead of giving us three links to see what you are doing.  If you create an empty vimrc file, then vim sets `'nocompatible'` during startup:  see `:help 'cp'`.  If you are having trouble with ESC in a terminal (not gvim) then see `:help xterm-cursor-keys` and other paragraphs in that section.

Comment: @pepper_chico `InsertLeave` is the trigger you are looking for, it should not (usually) have any delay. If it does there, try to find out the cause.

Comment: @Kent I have already looked at the reason of this, and it's related with `'nocompatible'` mode, by default, it does have this delay on `ESC`, as I said, I tested this with an empty `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR, `set ttimeout=100` (or less) and InsertLeave auto-commands will be processed much sooner (specifically, in that many milliseconds).

`:imap`ing `<Esc>` will cause cursor keys and function keys to stop working in insert mode, so don't do that. With the improved timeout, using the InsertLeave autocommand should be the way to go. I'd try and help with the cursor positioning problem you mention, but there isn't enough explanation of that to address it.

There are a lot of settings in vim that are related to responding to pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Vim might receive an escape for two main reasons:

1. the user pressed escape on its own, or
2. the user pressed an arrow key or function key that produced an escape sequence.

When it sees an escape in insert mode, vim cannot leave insert mode immediately but has to wait to find out if it is

1. part of an escape sequence generated by a function key, or
2. part of a multi-key mapping.

For the ultimate in fast escape handling you can set the option **noesckeys** which turns off the recognition of the special keys `<Left>`, `<Right>`, `<F1>`, etc. in insert mode. When vim is in compatible mode (what you got when you had no vimrc) this is the default behavior and explains why your InsertLeave autocommand was processed immediately. The documentation notes that the **esckeys** settings does not affect the processing of mappings which leads to the second topic.

Vim allows you to create a mapping for a sequence of keys, even when some prefix of that sequence is already mapped to some other action (either by another user mapping or a default action). When vim sees a key it will look to see if there is mapping that starts with that key. If there is only one and it is the key on its own, the mapping can be processed immediately. If there are multiple mappings beginning with the key then vim must wait to see if you complete one of the mappings.

Besides **esckeys** discussed above, Vim has several options for controlling whether it waits and for how long. These are

1. **timeout**, which controls whether vim uses a timeout to decide if a mapping is complete;
2. **ttimeout**, which controls whether vim uses a timeout to decide if an escape sequence is complete;
3. **timeoutlen**, which controls how long vim waits to see if a mapping is complete; and
4. **ttimeoutlen**, which control how long vim waits to see if an escape sequence is complete.

When **timeout** is off (**notimeout**) vim will wait indefinitely for a mapping to be completed. For instance, if **notimeout** is set and you have a mapping `:inoremap teh\  the\` to fix this common type (you would actually use an `iabbrev` for this in real life), and you typed <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> nothing will be added to the buffer until you either press <kbd>Space</kbd>, in which case the mapping occurs and `the` is added to the buffer; or you press some other key, causing the original `teh` to be added then processing the next key.

The **ttimeout** option is only consulted when **notimeout** is set (vim uses timeouts for both whenever *timeout* is set). With **nottimeout** set, vim will wait indefinitely after getting an escape to see if it is part of an escape sequence. If you set **notimeout**, **nottimeout**, and **showmode** you can see that when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode that vim remains in insert mode until some other key is pressed *that isn't part of an escape sequence*. A silly trick is to type <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> with these settings (make sure you are in an xterm) and watch the cursor move to the left.

Finally, when it is using timeouts, vim uses **timeoutlen** and **ttimeoutlen** to decide how long to wait. The defaults settings are `timeoutlen=1000`, which means a one second timeout, and `ttimeoutlen=-1` which means use the value of **timeout**. Now, one second is probably ok for the mappings but is way longer than is needed for recognizing escape sequences. Vim doesn't truly leave insert mode until it sees the escape and the relevant timeouts have expired. Oddly, vim will remove the **showmode** insert mode indicator right away after seeing the escape but not fire InsertLeave until after the timeout has passed (it adds the indicator back if a mapping/escape sequence is seen before the timeout expires). The vim documentation suggests trying `ttimeoutlen=100` but I think you could go even shorter, e.g. 50, without any problems with messed up special keys.

Now that I've researched this I'm going to go around and make sure I set `ttimeoutlen=50` everyplace I use vim and maybe even lower **timeoutlen** too.

Comment: Thanks but, I have read the section on timeouts when @benjifisher commented on Mar 15. At the time I have tried and what I found was that, the timeouts are of no help for me since when I try to trigger a selection over a pattern on InsertLeave, like the script tries to do with a ESC mapping, it doesn't select where I ask it to, it selects in a displaced spot.

Comment: Ah, even though your explanation is just what I've read about a week ago.... I've figured the issue with InsertLeave! it's was an unrelated issue that was registering the autocommand several times, so, when there was an InsertLeave, the scripting was selecting and deselecting like crazy. I noticed this because the status line flickered a bit on ESC, and so I figured out there were mutiple executions of the function I wanted to trigger just once. Anyway, I think this answer is full of details, etc, and, even thought it didn't solve my problem, it answers the question.

Comment: I'll also set `ttimeoutlen=50` from now on my `.vimrc`