# Remapping the escape key breaks nocompatible in vim

Tags: linux, vim, neocomplete

I'm trying to get a more sublime/atom-esq feeling when using vim. One of the things I've set up is neocomplete to mimic the other editor's autocomplete behavior.

I wanted the `<ESC>` key to close a completion popup if one were open, or behave normally otherwise. I came up with this solution:

```
inoremap <expr><ESC> pumvisible() ? neocomplete#cancel_popup() : "\<ESC>"
```

This seems to work fine (ESC behaves as one might expect), but it appears to break nocompatible - the arrow keys no longer work as expected in insert mode, they insert A/B/C/D and then a newline (depending on which key I hit).

Adding `set nocompatible` after the aforementioned line doesn't do anything (I've already got it set in the first couple lines of my vimrc), and typing `:set nocompatible` at runtime has no effect. The only way to fix this is by removing the remapping.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: This question isn't really a duplicate but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22677880/166955) can help explain what's going on.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I don't suppose there's a way around it?

Comment: I don't know of a way around it in the terminal. It's okay to do this sort of mapping if you are using gvim, though, since it gets the special keys directly instead of as escape sequences.